# Getting the minimum value from a binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find out the minimum value from a binary search tree,

```cpp
struct Node {
    int value;     
    Node *smaller; 
    Node *greater; 

    explicit Node(int value = 0, Node *smaller = nullptr, Node *greater = nullptr)
            : value(value)
            , smaller(smaller)
            , greater(greater)
    {
    }
};


struct BinarySearchTree {
    Node *root; // koren stromu

    explicit BinarySearchTree(Node *root = nullptr)
            : root(root)
    {
    }
};

class ValueNotExistsException : public std::exception {
};
```

that's how my BST is defined now I need to find out the min value:

```cpp
int min(const BinarySearchTree *tree) {
    /* code goes here */ 
}
```

I need to use the exact function. I've tried it with a node implementation like this:

```cpp
struct BinarySearchTree* current = tree;  
  
while (current->smaller!= NULL)  
{  
    current = current->smaller;  
}  
return(current->value);
```

The `current->value` does not behave as expected. My problem is that  when I declare my current it says:

`Cannot initialize a variable of type struct BinarySearchTree * with an lvalue of type const BinarySearchTree *`

Comment: What does "it doesn't work clearly" mean?

Comment: `BinarySearchTree` doesn't have a member named `smaller`. Now, what type **does** have a member named `smaller`?

Comment: "it doesn't work clearly" is not a problem description. When posting a question, describe the specific problem, i.e. what exactly happens and why that is wrong, and quote any errors in full.

Comment: okey i edited it sorry

Comment: Look at the tree `const BinarySearchTree *tree`, look at the current `BinarySearchTree *current`. Do you see the difference?

Answer (score 0):

- You have to return `value` instead of `smaller`.
- You have to extract the `root` from the `BinarySearchTree`.
- The place of `*` in `struct *BinarySearchTree current = tree;` is wrong.

```
int min(const BinarySearchTree *tree) {

    struct Node* current = tree->root;

    while (current->smaller!= NULL)
    {
        current = current->smaller;
    }
    return(current->value);

}
```

Comment: `struct *BinarySearchTree` doesn't look like C++ to me.

Comment: thanks thats seems to be the good one, also how do i implement / throw that ValueNotExistsException    exception if that value doesnt exists ,like that? return (current->value ? current->value: throw ValueNotExistsException() );

Comment: @MICHAEL -- What value are you referring to?  A BST has at least one node, so there will always be a minimum.

Comment: i mean if the tree is empty

Comment: What you would be checking for is if the passed in `tree` is `nullptr`, or `tree->root` is nullptr.  It shouldn't even get to the `while` loop, or assigning anything to `current` if any of those values are `nullptr`.